# Is $X_t=42+t^2W_t^3+tW_t^2+\int_0^t3W_udu+\int_0^tW_u^3dW_u$ a martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I'm really stuck with this problem.

> Is $X_t$ or $X_t-\mathbb{E}(X_t)$ a martingale, where $$
> X_t=42+t^2W_t^3+tW_t^2+\int_0^t3W_udu+\int_0^tW_u^3dW_u ?
> $$

There is a hint, to find first $dX_t$, and then it says the solution will be very short.

Using Ito formula I find:
$$
d(42)=0
$$
$$
d(t^2W_t^3)=2tW_t^3dt+3t^2W_t^2dW_t+3t^2W_tdt
$$
$$
d(tW_t^2)=W_t^2dt+2tW_tdW_t+2tdt
$$
$$
d(\int_0^t3W_udu)=3W_tdt
$$
$$
d(\int_0^tW_u^3dW_u)=W_t^3dW_t
$$
(the last one is a bit tricky. First, using Ito formula we find
$$
d(W_t^4)=4W_t^3dW_t+6W_t^2dt,
$$
and thus
$$
\int_0^tW_u^3dW_u=\frac14W_t^4-\frac32\int_0^tW_u^2du.
$$
The rest is straightforward application of Ito formula.)

Then I combine everything and find
$$
d(X_t)=(2tW_t^3+3t^2W_t+W_t^2+2t+3W_t)dt+(3t^2W_t^2+2tW_t+W_t^3)dW_t.
$$
Also after some calculations I find
$$
\mathbb{E}(X_t)=42+t^2
$$

How is one supposed to infer from this whether $X_t$ or $X_t-\mathbb{E}(X_t)$ a martingale I have no idea...

I tried to solve it directly, using increments of the Wiener process, but the problem gets so messy so quick, that it is obvious there has to be a better way to do this.

Comment: Hint: A process $Y$ with dynamics $dY_t = A_t dt + B_t dW_t$ for predictable processes $A,B$ is a (local) martingale iff $A_t = 0$

Comment: @user6247850 thanks. So neither of the quantities in question are martingales, as it seems...

Comment: Yeah, doesn't look like it.